# Arrays LC3, sort elements 2 by two

Tags: arrays, sorting, lc3

So this is my task "Sort the array in decreasing order of score. Highest score first. Note that the sorted array will be ordered by score but each record has an associated name that needs to go with the record."

I know how to sort in LC3 when I just have grades, but not when I have to sort them along with their names.

Comment: Please post an example of your current array, and how you want it to be after sorting.

Comment: ARRAY
             Scores
x3500 [58]
x3501 [David]
x3502 [98]
x3503 [Martha]
x3504 [28]
x3505 [Jessica]
x3506 [-1]

we have to sort them on decreasing order

Comment: So I have an score and right below I have the student that the score belongs to, and I have to sort them in decreasing order